# Javascript , scope problem ... not very experienced with javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, this, getjson

Forgive my inexperience but here's the problem, I have some 2 functions with 1 of them calling .getJSON and I need to call the 2nd function from within the first function's getJSON callback .. I am having a lot of trouble.

Here is a simplified version of what is going on.

```
MyDialog.Widget.prototype._myFunction1 = function(data) {
var self = this;

var renderEntry = function(tr,booltf) {
    $('<a href="javascript:{}">&nbsp;</a>')
            .addClass("iconbutton")
            .appendTo(tr.insertCell(0))
            .click(function() {
                $.getJSON(
                    "/command/button",
                    null,
                    function(data) {
                                      self.myFunction2(); //self isn't in scope?
                                      //this.myFunction2(); //this is actually 'this' for XHR request
                    },
                    "json"
                );
            });
//more code here (including the invoking of renderEntry()
}

MyDialog.Widget.prototype.myFunction2 = function()
{
 //Ton of code
}
```

The problem is in the callback function of the .getJSON , I want to call myFunction2 but I can't get it to call it... using 'this.myFunction2()' I am trying to access a 'myFunction2' inside the XHR request (that's what i see through firebug), and using the var 'self' that I create before doesn't work either because it isn't in scope I think, firebug doesn't show any variable 'self' when inside the callback function, and of course it just doesn't work when I try it out.

Any ideas? any more elaboration needed?

Comment: If `self` weren't in the scope you would get an error when trying to do `self.something`. Maybe your problem is something else?

Answer (score 5):

Your code is fine in terms of scope. `self` is in scope and references `this` just like you want it to. Your debugger might not show it because it isn't in the *local* function scope, but that doesn't mean it won't be resolved correctly.

A simpler case can be easily demonstrated as follows:

```
var foo = {
   fn: function(){ console.log('Called!'); },
   invoker: function(){
      var self = this,
          local = function(){ setTimeout(function(){
                     setTimeout(function(){ self.fn(); }, 1000);
                  }, 1000); };
      local();
   }
};

foo.invoker();
```

- **Make sure your request is succeeding.**
- Remove the `"json"` argument (`$.getJSON` only has 3 parameters).
- Post more code.

Answer (score -1):

where are you calling the renderEntry() ? That's the key part of the code. It doesn't know self because it wasn't initialized when the renderEntry() function was called. The self is initialized when you call _myFunction1 and it goes dead when the function finishes execution.

You do realize that you are only *initializing* the renderEntry function and not *invoking* it?

Comment: No idea, what you mean by "goes dead", and I have strong suspicion that it isn't anything that is true of JS.